# Accessing Linux server via VPN or Certificate based ssh?

Tags: ssh, security, vpn

My company has a fairly common security setup where you need to log in via VPN,  when outside the company network in order to get access to the servers.  The biome is mostly Windows machines.

I'm hard at work currently, setting up a repository/build Debian environment that needs to be accesible from the outside world.  I have set up certificate based `ssh` using OpenSSH.

**My question is as follows:**

Is there any added security in using the VPN setup as opposed to just opening the SSH port to the internet and allowing the SSH certificates to authenticate the users?

It seems to me that letting people who would not usually be there, inside the VPN to access a single service is allowing that user way more access than needed. But I'm not too familiar with VPN, so are there any added benefits I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are worrying about the security of the transport or about the login/connection-setup security. I never worried about the former (assuming the encryption is not broken yet), but the latter was in my case more secure as it used a hardware token generator **in addition to** a password/pin, where the ssh connections normally only require a single password (or a private key protected (hopefully) by a single password).

Comment: From a security perspective, they are the same (I mean a certificate-based VPN). From a usability perspective, SSH is usually harder for windows users. Additionally you might want to consider not using a standard port for SSH because the standard port is spammed to death.

Comment: @nablex I am the default port internally, but i fully expect to expose a different port to the internet. The firewall will take care of that. The access will be used primarily for accessing GIT archives, and since the GIT client we use can use certificates, Windows users should survive... barely:) But i', glad to hear they are mostly identical.

Comment: @Anthon Thank you for the input. Are you saying you can implement RSAtokens and the like with OpenSSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VPN is more secure that opening a ssh port to the world. You can give users access to all machines, inside your intranet by only opening one port for VPN access from outside. You do not need to open, for instance ssh, public port on each server. Servers are completely hidden to the world except one VPN gateway. I think it's better. And no matter if you want to give your users access to additional services, there will be still one open VPN port to the world.

Obviously you can firewall all access inside your intranet too if you like.
Moreover if you open SSH ports on the server to the outside world you surely will need some extra security like port knocking and `fail2ban` to stop the madness on that port.

So, VPN is just better and more flexible way of accessing local services for "road warriors". I consider it as good practice to use, almost a standard.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no added security, both have the same point of weakness which is a port open to the world.